# terraform - Ecs cluster doesn't show ec2 container instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

i'm using terraform to create a cluster on aws. When i run my code it spins up an ec2 instance but it doesn't show up in my container instances even though i have a capacity provider and autoscaling group in my terraform code. When i run the code i expect for the ec2 instance to show as the infrastructure for my Ecs cluster. At the moment it creates the ec2 but the my cluster hasn't registered the ec2 container instance so I can’t run any tasks.

https://github.com/Dandiggas/FirstWebApp/blob/main/terraform.txt

Comment: Please work through the troubleshooting steps here: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ecs-instance-unable-join-cluster

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your EC2 instance is not joining the cluster. You can do this by setting up the following userdata for the EC2 instance (where MyCluster is the name of your cluster):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "ECS_CLUSTER=MyCluster" >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

Also make sure your EC2 instance has internet access or a VPC endpoint to communicate with the ECS API.

See for more information:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bootstrap_container_instance.html

Comment: I tried this and the Ec2 still didn't show up in my cluster. All the network settings are default. When i create a cluster on the console everything works fine

Comment: Check out the following example: https://gist.github.com/alexjeen/984dd2b092ffa49e1c3bf4f6505d0ebe you must make sure the EC2 instance has a instance profile with a role to communicate to ECS